# GeoServer + MongoDB + Boundless: CQL not working

Tags: geoserver, boundless-suite, mongodb

After adding a collection of jsonArray data to my mongodb database I wanted to filter it with CQL, but it doesn't seem to work. My query goes like this:

```
user.name like '%username%'
```

When I apply this filter all my points disappear.
The only CQL filter that seems to work is when I try an int value on a root property:

```
id_str = 123
```

Versions I am using:

- mongodb: 3.0.2
- geoserver: 2.7.0
- geoserver-exts: 2.7-SNAPSHOT